# Existence of Finite Fields

Tags: abstract-algebra, field-theory, finite-fields

I was reading the following example from Dummit & Foote, Algebra:

[image]
[image]

Okay, I get it, except for one point: I get that by the minimality of the splitting field, any subfield of the splitting field containing all the roots of the given polynomial must be the whole splitting field *provided* that the subfield in question contains the base field. How do we know that in this case, $\mathbb{F}$ contains $\mathbb{F}_p$? I.e., how do we know that every element of $\mathbb{F}_p$ is a root of the polynomial $x^{p^n}-x$?

Thanks!

Comment: $x^{p^n}$ is $(((x^p)^p)^p\ldots)^p$ where $p$ appears $n$ times. But $x^p=x$ in $\mathbb{F}_p$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here are two purely abstract reasons why $\mathbb{F}_p \subseteq \mathbb{F}$.

**Reason 1:** If $K$ is any field and $f$ any polynomial over $K$, the splitting field of $f$ over $K$ is, in particular, defined to be a *field extension of $K$*, so $K$ is automatically contained in the splitting field.

**Reason 2:** Every field of characteristic $p$ contains $\mathbb{F}_p$ as a subfield.

Answer (score 2):

This is a corollary of [Fermat's little theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fermat%27s_little_theorem), which says that all $x\in \Bbb F_p$ we have $x^p = x$ (or, in some phrasings, that for $x\neq 0$ we have $x^{p-1} = 1$, but that's the same thing). Now note that $x^{p^n} = (\cdots((x^p)^p)^p\cdots)^p$. One may also quote [Lagrange's theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lagrange%27s_theorem_(group_theory)) on the multiplicative group of the field to get the same result.

Answer (score 1):

It is the field generated by the roots. If it contains a root $x$, it contains its inverse $y$ and$xy=1$.

Answer (score 1):

$\mathbf F$ contains (a field isomorphic to) $\mathbf F_p$ because any  field contains $1$, hence all  multiples of $1$, which make a field isomorphic to  $\mathbf F_p$.

Also every element of $\mathbf F_p$ satisfies the equation $x^p=x$ (that's what  *lil' Fermat* asserts), so iteratively
$$x^{p^n}=\bigl(x^p\bigr)^{p^{n-1}}=x\vphantom{h}^{p^{n-1}}=x.$$