# Why $[\mathbb{F}_{p}(\alpha): \mathbb{F}_{p^n}] = p$?

Tags: abstract-algebra, field-theory, galois-theory, finite-fields, extension-field

I was reading the second answer of the following question here [Why $x^{p^n}-x+1$ is irreducible in ${\mathbb{F}_p}$ only when $n=1$ or $n=p=2$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/122274/why-xpn-x1-is-irreducible-in-mathbbf-p-only-when-n-1-or-n-p-2/4175356#4175356) :

Prove that $f(X) = X^{p^n} - X + 1$ is irreducible over $\mathbb F_{p}$ if and only if either $n = 1$ or $n = p = 2.$

And the book gave the following hint:
Note that if $\alpha$ is a root, then so is $\alpha + a$ for any $a \in \mathbb F_{p^n}.$
Show that this implies $\mathbb F_{p}(\alpha)$ contains $\mathbb F_{p^n}$ and that $[\mathbb F_p(\alpha) : \mathbb F_{p^n}] = p$

**Here is the answer I am referring to:**

I have another solution that might be easier to follow.

Let $\alpha$ be a root of $q(x)=x^{p^n}-x+1$. Note that $\alpha + a$ is also a root of $q(x)$ for all $a \in \mathbb{F}_{p^n}$. Consider cyclic muplicative group $\mathbb{F}_{p^n}^{\times} = \mathbb{F}_{p}(\theta)$ for some generator $\theta$, then $\alpha + \theta$ and $\alpha$ are roots of $q(x)$, so they belong to $\mathbb{F}_{p}(\alpha)$ which shows that $\theta \in \mathbb{F}_{p}(\alpha)$, hence $\mathbb{F}_{p^n} \subset \mathbb{F}_{p}(\alpha)$. We have $\mathbb{F}_{p} \subset  \mathbb{F}_{p^n} \subset \mathbb{F}_{p}(\alpha)$.

If $p(x)$ is irreducible over $\mathbb{F}_p$, then $[\mathbb{F}_{p}(\alpha):\mathbb{F}_{p}] = p^n$, hence $|\mathbb{F}_{p}(\alpha)|=p^{pn}$. Consider the endomorphism $\sigma$: $\mathbb{F}_{p}(\alpha) \to \mathbb{F}_{p}(\alpha)$ which sends $\alpha \to \alpha^{p^n}$ (why it is a endomorphism?). Consider subgroup of automorphism $H = \langle \sigma \rangle$. $H$ fixes $\mathbb{F}_{p^n}$ (Why?), so we have $[\mathbb{F}_{p}(\alpha): \mathbb{F}_{p^n}]=|H|=p$ ($\sigma^p$ is identity map). Then $[\mathbb{F}_{p}(\alpha):\mathbb{F}_{p}] = [\mathbb{F}_{p}(\alpha): \mathbb{F}_{p^n}][\mathbb{F}_{p^n}:\mathbb{F}_{p}]$ which means $p^{n}=pn$ and this only happens when $n=1$ or $n=p=2$.

**My questions are:**

1- Why is the field containing all the roots of the given polynomial is $\mathbb{F}_{p}(\alpha)$ and not $\mathbb{F}_{p^n}(\alpha)$?

2- Why $[\mathbb{F}_{p}(\alpha): \mathbb{F}_{p^n}] = p$?

Could someone clarify these points to me please?

Comment: I just wanted to point out that your answers are always so valuable to me and they are to the point @JyrkiLahtonen I was actually waiting for your replies to my questions through the whole day yesterday

Comment: Unlucky timing. Don't worry about it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your questions are ok in the sense that the answers to both your questions are negative: It is not always true that $\Bbb{F}_p(\alpha)$ would be a splitting field, nor is it always true that we would have $[\Bbb{F}_p(\alpha):\Bbb{F}_{p^n}]=p$. Simply because it is often possible to choose the zero $\alpha$ in such a way that $\Bbb{F}_p(\alpha)$ does not contain the field $\Bbb{F}_{p^n}$ as a subfield. Meaning that the degree
$[\Bbb{F}_p(\alpha):\Bbb{F}_{p^n}]$ is non-sensical!

---

The hint is correct: if $\alpha$ is *any* root of $f(x)$, all the roots are of the form $\alpha+z$, where $z\in\Bbb{F}_{p^n}$. This implies that the splitting field $E$ must contain $\Bbb{F}_{p^n}$ and one of the zeros $\alpha$. Obviously $\alpha\notin\Bbb{F}_{p^n}$, so $E=\Bbb{F}_{p^n}(\alpha)$.

It is also correct that $[E:\Bbb{F}_{p^n}]=p$. This is because the Galois group
$Gal(\Bbb{F}_{p^n}(\alpha)/\Bbb{F}_{p^n})$ is generated by the Frobenius automorphism $F:z\mapsto z^{p^n}$. As the old answers explain, the orbit of $\alpha$ under iterates of $F$ consists of the elements $\alpha+j, j\in\Bbb{F}_p$.
There are $p$ of those, so $[\Bbb{F}_{p^n}(\alpha):\Bbb{F}_{p^n}]=p$. These together do imply that $E=\Bbb{F}_{p^{np}}$ and the claimed reducibility result follows.

On the other hand, the degree of the extension $m:=[K:\Bbb{F}_p]$, $K=\Bbb{F}_p(\alpha)$, is in the dark, because it may depend on the choice of $\alpha$. It takes $p$ iterations of $F$ to get back to $\alpha$, so we always have $p\mid m$.

However, if $p\nmid n$, the polynomial $f(x)$ always has $p$ roots in $\Bbb{F}_{p^p}$. This can be seen by taking a peek at [an old answer of mine](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/581159/11619), or more simply by the following argument.
The polynomials $g_a(x):=x^p-x-a$, $a\in\Bbb{F}_p\setminus\{0\}$, [are known to be irreducible over the prime field](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/81583/11619).
If $\alpha$ is a root of $g_a(x)$, then by the familiar induction of $j$, we have
$$
\alpha^{p^j}=\alpha+ja.\qquad(*)
$$
When $p\nmid n$, we can select $a\in\Bbb{F}_p^*$ in such a way that $n\cdot a=-1$,
so $a=-1/n$ if you don't mind the mild abuse of notation. The equation
$(*)$ thus says that a root of $g_{-1/n}(x)$ is also a root of $f(x)$. As $g_{-1/n}(x)$ has all its $p$ roots in $\Bbb{F}_{p^p}\setminus\Bbb{F}_p$, the claim follows.

The appearance of $g_{-1/n}(x)$ can be explained by a trace condition. Pablo Rotondo already made the observation that it is a factor of $f(x)$ in a comment under [the linked question](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/579659/11619). IIRC that tipped me off to some extent :-)

---

If the hint in the book, indeed, suggests that $\Bbb{F}_p(\alpha)$ should be the splitting field, that is a bit careless. I suspect that whoever gave that hint had in mind a contrapositive argument like: *Assume that $f(x)$ is irreducible. Let $\alpha$ be one of its roots. As all the extensions of finite fields are normal, it follows that $E=\Bbb{F}_p(\alpha)$ is the splitting field. $\ldots$*. In other words, may be this part of the hint was intended to only apply, when $f(x)$ truly is irreducible.

As there are plenty of elements fulfilling the trace condition in my linked answer, I would be very surprised if it were not always possible to choose the root $\alpha$ in such a way $\Bbb{F}_p(\alpha)$ actually is the splitting field $E$. This always happens (desirable from the point of view of the hint) when $n=p$. The splitting field $E$ is a degree $p^2$ extension of the prime field. But no zeros of $f(x)$ can be in the (only!) subfield $M=\Bbb{F}_{p^p}$ as $f(z)=1$ for all the elments $z\in M$.

Comment: But I notice that $\alpha ^ p$ is also a root, how will this help me in proving that $[E: \mathbb F_{p^n}] = p$ with the $E$ you mentioned in the second paragraph?

Comment: @Emptymind $\alpha^p$ is, indeed, a root. So it must be one of the elements $\alpha+z, z\in\Bbb{F}_{p^n}$. The polynomial $g(x)=x^{p^n}-x=f(x)-1$ is additive, so
$$g(\alpha^p-\alpha)=g(\alpha^p)-g(\alpha)=[f(\alpha^p)-1]-[f(\alpha)-1]=-1+1=0.$$ 
The zeros of $g(x)$ are exactly the elements of $\Bbb{F}_{p^n}$, so $\alpha^p-\alpha\in\Bbb{F}_{p^n}$.

Comment: The result $[E:\Bbb{F}_{p^n}]=p$ is a consequence of the facts that A) $E=\Bbb{F}_{p^n}(\alpha)$ and B) the $\Bbb{F}_{p^n}$-conjugates of $\alpha$ are $\alpha^{p^n}=\alpha+1$ and all the other elements $\alpha+j, j=0,1,2,\ldots,p-1$.

Comment: I did not get $B)$ in what you said ..... But from what I observed, can I conclude that $$[E: \mathbb F_{p^n}] \leq p$$ or no?

Comment: Why the $\mathbb F_{p^n}$ conjugates of $\alpha$ look like this? And how will this help me in the proof?

Comment: The degree of the minimal polynomial of $\alpha$ over $\Bbb{F}_{p^n}$ is equal to the extension degree $[E:\Bbb{F}_{p^n}]$. And you get the  $\Bbb{F}_q$ conjugates by applying the generator of the Galois group $z\mapsto z^q$ iteratively.

Comment: I was thinking about completing my argument by saying that then that of $1, \alpha, \alpha^2,\dots, \alpha^p$ are linearly dependent but then I do not know how to complete

Comment: what is $q$ in relation to $p^n$?

Comment: $q=p^n$. Did you take a look at [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2171681/11619)? It's the same method.

Comment: Can not I say that since $[\mathbb F_{p^n}(\alpha): \mathbb F_{p^n} ] \leq p$(is this something correct I can conclude) and from the linear dependence argument the required follows?

Comment: Forget linear dependence. You want to use Galois theory. Or, alternatively, properties of finite fields. If $K=\Bbb{F}_q$ and $\beta$ is algebraic over $K$, the degree of the extension $K(\beta)/K$ is equal to the smallest positive integer $\ell$ such that $\beta^{q^\ell}=\beta$. That's what Lubin (and all the other answerers actually) is using.

Comment: (cont'd) With $q=p^n$ and $\alpha$ any zero of $f(x)$ we get at $\ell=p$. Done.

Comment: Yeah this is exactly what I do not understand, why specifically this condition? Is there a proof of this fact?

Comment: I looked at Lubin's answer and this line was the thing that I actually do not understand "the number of $k$-conjugates of $\alpha$ is precisely $p$, and the irreducible factor $g$ of $F$ is of degree $p$", is there a proof for this?

Comment: Is this what you are trying to say to me and what Lubin was trying to say in his answer "$x \to x^p$ is an automorphism sending $r$ to $r-a$ for any root $r$ of the polynomial. This operation is cyclic of order $p$, so that one can get from any root to any other by applying the automorphism several times.  The Galois group thus acts transitively on the roots, which is equivalent to irreducibility."?

Comment: Is the result you stated in your last 2 comments is stated in any book?

Comment: A proof is based on [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2848397/11619) (picked it because it is an excerpt from D&F). The size of the field $\Bbb{F}_{p^n}(\alpha)$ is $p^m$, where $m$ is the smallest positive integer such that A) $z^{p^m}=z$ for all $z\in\Bbb{F}_{p^n}$ and B) $\alpha^{p^m}=\alpha$. Condition A) holds if and only if $n\mid m$ (by that result from D&F again), and condition B) then dictates $m=pn$ as the smallest multiple of $n$ as per Lubin and others.

Comment: But, yeah, you can think about it in terms of the action of the Galois group as well. I'm sure D&F explain the Galois theory of finite fields. All the books at that level do.

Comment: Let me try to rationalize it :)

Comment: I am confused, what exactly is the Frobenius map? Does it take $\alpha $ to $\alpha^p$ or $\alpha^q$, if it takes it to power $q,$ then how I will get the conjugates you mentioned?

Comment: The way I use the term *Frobenius automorphism* depends on what I think of as the base field. When thinking about the Galois group of the extension $L/K$, both finite field, I think of the Frobenius map as the natural generator of $Gal(L/K)$. That is, the mapping $z\mapsto z^{|K|}$. The mapping $z\mapsto z^p$ is then the generator of $Gal(L/\Bbb{Z}_p)$. Sorry about not making that clear. Anyway, an element is a fixed point of a cyclic group $G$ of automorphisms if and only if it is a fixed point of a generator of $G$.

Comment: But then how you will get the conjugates? You are writing $\alpha^{p^n}$ above to get the conjugates.

Comment: The conjugates = the automorphic images = the set of zeros of the minimal polynomial over $K$. That's basic Galois theory.

Comment: Whenever $L/K$ is a Galois extension, and $\alpha\in L$ you get the degree of the extension $K(\alpha)/K$ by figuring out how many distinct $K$-conjugates $\alpha$ has. The point is that in the case of finite fields the mapping $z\mapsto z^{|K|}$ is the generator of the Galois group for every choice of $K$. Here it is easy to figure out the number of conjugates ($=p$) when $K=\Bbb{F}_{p^n}$, but it is more taxing when we choose $K=\Bbb{F}_p$, which is the game I am playing. Don't get stuck with some slightly inaccurate posting somebody else made.

Comment: (cont'd) I may be willing to claim that I understand this better than D&F, don't tempt me :-)

Comment: You should :))) you understand the subject very well! @Jyrki Lahtonen

Answer (score 1):

1. $\mathbb{F}_p(\alpha)$ is a splitting field of the polynomial $q$ (when $q$ in irreducible). I'm not quite sure but I think that from general finite field theory, we know that a polynomial on any finite field either has no root in that field or splits in that field. So in fact, $\mathbb{F}_p(\alpha)$ is a splitting field for $q$ (when $q$ is irreducible).
2. Here, $\sigma$ is $F^n$ where $F$ denotes the Frobenius map. It is an endomorphism since $F$ is an endomorphism as the characteristic of $\mathbb{F}_p(\alpha)$ is $p$. $H$ fixes $\mathbb{F}_{p^n}$ beacause $\mathbb{F}_{p^n}$ is the splitting field of $X^{p^n}-X$ over $\mathbb{F}_p$. To get that $[\mathbb{F}_p(\alpha):\mathbb{F}_{p^n}] = p$, we want to prove that $H$ is the Galois group of $\mathbb{F}_p(\alpha)$ over $\mathbb{F}_{p^n}$. It is clear from what we have said that $H$ is a subset of the Galois group. Let $\tau$ be an $\mathbb{F}_{p^n}$-automorphisme of $\mathbb{F}_p(\alpha)$. Again by general finite field theory, we know that $\tau$ is a power of the Frobenius map hence $\tau = F^m$ for an integer $m$. As $\mathbb{F}_{p^n}$ is the kernel of $F^{n}$, Euclidean division shows that $k$ must be a multiple of $n$ so we get that $\tau \in H$. So we have $H = Gal(\mathbb{F}_p(\alpha)/\mathbb{F}_{p^n})$. Thus, $[\mathbb{F}_p(\alpha) : \mathbb{F}_{p^n}] = |H| = p$.

Comment: I don't feel like my answer is super clear, feel free to ask for more precisions.

Comment: what is the relation between p and q then?

Comment: What do you mean ? p is a prime number and q is the polynomial we are interested in

Comment: I think 1 is not an answer for my question.

Comment: and 2 also does not answer my second question

Comment: In 1) I proved that $\mathbb{F}_p(\alpha)$ is the splitting field of $q$, i.e. the field containing all the roots of the given polynomial.

Comment: but you did not told me anything about the number of roots of your polynomial and where you get this result

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/152233/discussion-between-valentin-massicot-and-emptymind).